# Does using Linq-TO-SQL on a WCF service automatically create static classes filled with table data?

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql, orm

If i generate Linq-To-SQL or ORM classes with entities and relationships on a wcf service, does this automatically generate a static version of the entire database with the relatiohsipships on the server side so I am not having to deal directly with the SQL database but in-memory collections in the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.  LINQ-To-SQL will only hydrate those objects that are fetched, not the entire database (unless you somehow queried the entire database in the scope of a single DataContext).

Comment: is that a bad thing to do? scope the entire database and send it to the client as a *cached copy* of the database on client startup. insert update delete commands though WCF OperationContracts to directly update the database first then if successful in updating sql, update the local cached copy so that all view models reflect the change? I would see how this could be bad sending large chuncks of data at startup(DDoS, etc). I can get this type of model to work. It just doesnt seem to be the right way of doing this

Comment: @Christopher Leach - Yeah, I would say that's definitely a bad thing to do, even if it were feasible. What makes you think you'd want to cache the entire database? Typically you would only want to cache entities that are fetched often, and when having 100% up-to-date data isn't critical. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: its just that each time i call the wcf service for data that it is always creating a new observable collection. when a change in data occurs i have to notify each collection in memory of the change through IList, Linq and replace. i would love it if i could find some one to have one static collection of the entire database client or server side that when changes are made the static class is the thing that is being changed. i dont mind using linq-to-sql logic to control the datastorage. I would love for someone to correct my errorous programming practices for the benefit of having one less dudd